# How long should missForest take to impute data for my data set (n=7896)

Tags: r, random-forest, imputation

I have a data set with n=7896 and 39 variables. 9 are continuous (integer) and 30 are binary factors. 79493 data points are missing of the 307944 total data points. I am attempting to impute the missing data using missForest, but I'm unsure how long it should take to run.

Roughly 30 minutes have passed and it is still on the first iteration. I'm running this on a Lenovo Thinkpad X220t. Code is below.

```
> data=read.csv(file.choose())
> data$ï..Gen = as.factor(data$ï..Gen)
> binary <- c(3:8)
> data[,binary] <- lapply(data[,binary], factor)
> binarya <- c(16:39)
> data[,binarya] <- lapply(data[,binarya], factor)
> View(data)
> set.seed(1337)
> data.mis <- prodNA(data, noNA=.1)
> missForest(data.mis, maxiter= 10, ntree=2001, variablewise=TRUE,decreasing=FALSE,verbose=TRUE,mtry=floor(sqrt(ncol(data.mis))),replace=TRUE, xtrue= data.mis)
  missForest iteration 1 in progress...
```

Should I lower the ntree or mtry perhaps? Or is my noNA too large or small? Is the seed number a problem? I've never worked with data imputation before, so I'm unsure how long this should take or if my parameters are even reasonable. The mtry value is the default.

Comment: From my experience it takes too long. Just subset the data and only use 200 rows. (to try to check if it works at all)

Comment: I canceled it and retried it with small ntree. ntree=11 takes just under a minute per iteration. I can run it overnight though with a bigger ntree and more iterations and see if I can get better imputation then.